# Set action for pressing Enter in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I used below code for my **edit text** so that when I press enter it does not go to new line and works like pressing button but it does not work, what's the problem?

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                    search();
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you set singleline = true in edittext?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `XML EditText`

```
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:singleLine="true"
```

It will automatically perform the same rather than going to new line. `Enter` will act like a `button`

Answer (score 1):

try this, it may help

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                search();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```